# Extracting map within a map using Pyspark

Tags: dictionary, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, explode

I have the following schema:

```
sitename: string (nullable = true)
 |-- publisherUid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- requestid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- deviceType: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vscore: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: map (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string
 |    |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
```

and I'm trying to extract sitename,publisherUid, requestid, deviceType, vscore_key, contents of value 1, contents of value 2

Comment: Share a sample input data and expected output

Comment: Could you please make your question little bit more clear, what do you mean by `contents of value 1, contents of value 2`?

Comment: Under vscore -> value; the value is an array which consists of data in the following format [metric1 -> 0.90 ,tier -> tier1, metric1-> 0.77]. I need to extract only two  values which is tier1 and 0.77 for all sitename, publisheruid,r equestid and devicetype.